# mvn clean verify fails integration tests : No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, integration-testing

When I run `mvn clean verify` it fails doing integration tests but when i run the tests from intelliJ they all pass. I'm using junit 5.

This is the stack trace:

```
04-09-2019 15:03:44.923 [it.soluxioni.ars.ArsApplication.main()] DEBUG it.soluxioni.ars.ArsApplication.logStarting - Running with Spring Boot v2.1.7.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.9.RELEASE
04-09-2019 15:03:44.923 [it.soluxioni.ars.ArsApplication.main()] INFO  it.soluxioni.ars.ArsApplication.logStartupProfileInfo - The following profiles are active: test
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:543)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'comunicationController' defined in file [/home/gavino/Work/ars/target/classes/it/soluxioni/ars/controllers/ComunicationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mailServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/gavino/Work/ars/target/classes/it/soluxioni/ars/services/MailServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:743)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:390)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1203)
    at it.soluxioni.ars.ArsApplication.main(ArsApplication.java:135)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mailServiceImpl' defined in file [/home/gavino/Work/ars/target/classes/it/soluxioni/ars/services/MailServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1658)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
```

This is the test class for testing OAuth2 authentication.

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ArsApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {IntegrationTestConfiguration.class})
public class OAuthResourceServerTestIT {

    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "asd";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "asd";
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

    private static final String NORMAL_USERNAME = "NormalUser";
    private static final String ADMIN_USERNAME = "Administrator";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "asd";

    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientRepository clientRepository;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webapp;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webapp)
                .apply(SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity())
                .alwaysDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .build();
       ....
       //in memory db setup

    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        ...
        //clean up db
    }

    @Test
    public void passwordGrant() throws Exception {
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "password");
        params.add("username", ADMIN_USERNAME);
        params.add("password", PASSWORD);
        params.add("scope", "read");


        ResultActions result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/oauth/token")
                .params(params)
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
                .accept(CONTENT_TYPE))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.content().contentType(CONTENT_TYPE));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPublicResourceWithAnonymousUser() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/public/hello")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

   ......
   //other tests


    private String obtainAccessToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        params.add("grant_type", "password");
        params.add("username", username);
        params.add("password", password);
        params.add("scope", "read");
        ResultActions result = mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/oauth/token")
                .params(params)
                .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.httpBasic(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
                .accept(CONTENT_TYPE));


        String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

        JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
        return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
    }
}
```

For testing i use an in memory h2 database
This is my test configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class IntegrationTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {

        JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtps");
        javaMailSender.setHost("smptp@test.it");
        javaMailSender.setPort(465);
        javaMailSender.setUsername("test@test.it");
        javaMailSender.setPassword("password");

        return javaMailSender;
    }
}
```

The problem looks like spring cannot autowire a javaMailSenderImpl(i tryed also with the interface but is's the same) that is request from my service.
The service implementation:

```
@Service
@Primary
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    private JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender;

    public MailServiceImpl(JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;
    }
   ...
   //methods
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>test.it</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ars</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <junit-platform-version>5.5.1</junit-platform-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <!-- <exclusions>
                 <exclusion>
                     &lt;!&ndash; declare the exclusion here &ndash;&gt;
                     <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                     <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
             </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.194</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ars</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>

        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>production</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>test</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

I run the test with the 'test' profile.

If i run 
`mvn clean test-compile failsafe:integration-test` 
all integration test runs and pass

Comment: In what folder is the `IntegrationTestConfiguration` located?

Comment: `IntegrationTestConfiguration` is into `src/test/configuration`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that maven starts your spring-boot web-app (without test dependencies before your tests are executed), because of:

```
<execution>
    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>start</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

I expect that you get the exact same error when you start your spring-boot-application with the profile test.

Would it make sense to place the `IntegrationTestConfiguration` in your main code and annotate it with `@Profile("test")`

**EDIT:** Or maybe you don't need your app to be started at all, please choose what works best for your case.

Comment: if i remove the execution tag  i got this: ` Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.7.RELEASE:stop (post-integration-test) on project ars: Spring application lifecycle JMX bean not found (fork is null). Could not stop application gracefully`

Comment: If you don't start then you should (of course) also don't stop it. But I never suggested to remove it. Instead please test whether you can run your application with the profile test, because that is what part of the code does.

Comment: Although maybe you don't actually need your running application in your integration tests, but that feels strange against what are you integrating then?

Comment: If i run the application with the test profile active it cannot start.

Comment: Okay, then first try without starting so removing: both pre-integration-test and post-integration-test

Comment: I moved the configuration into main package and annotated with Profile('test'). I also removed the tag executions but the app starts and after one second it exits without any error

Comment: And does you mvn build now succeed now it no longer tries to start the broken application?

Comment: Now i moved tha application-test.properties from test to main and now the app starts fine and mvn verify execute with no errors.

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it let you to the solution :-)

Comment: accepted! but i think you cannot see because my low reputation ;)